# User defined initial velocity for smoke simulation

Tags: scripting

my aim is to create a plugin for Blender which allows defining a specific initial velocity field on a grid for a smoke simulation. 
I'm rel. new to Blender and I didn't find anything on the internet related to it. I would really appreciate a little help/advise from somebody :)

The idea is of the tool is:
Presets: 
- Modell an object (closed surface. f.i. a bunny) which will represent the smoke
- Paint on it some weights/colors --> this represent the velocity of the smoke in direction of the facet normals. (this can be represented as a vortex sheet on the surface of the object) 
- Create a grid around the object with the painted vortex sheet

To do (scripting):
1) from the painted vortex sheet on the object recreate the entire initial velocity field on the grid

2) give this computed initial velocity field to blender's fluid solver, which will advect the particles i.o. to visualise the smoke

QUESTIONS:
1] Where can I find documentation on how to implement point 2) ? or could somebody give me a hint how to solve this?
2] Will python be enough for the tool? or do I need to code in c++ ?
4] Is there any function in Blender which can tell me if a voxel (of the grid) is inside or outside of the modelled surface (the bunny)?

Thanks!

Pablo